# Removing () from Python

Tags: python, sandbox

From this site: http://isisblogs.poly.edu/2012/10/26/escaping-python-sandboxes/

By removing modules and other functions, it is possible to somewhat secure python's environment. However, the site also shows how to break out of it by accessing the tuples (). Is there any way to also remove or disable ()?

Comment: It's not just `()` -- Any literal will do.  Try it with `().__class__.__bases__ == {}.__class__.__bases__` or `(1).__class__.__bases__`, or `[].__class__.__bases__` ... In all cases you end up with a reference to `object` which (if I understand Ned's hackery) is all you need.

Comment: As a side note, thanks for that link.  After reading it, I think I now finally understand Ned's hackery to do dangerous stuff with `eval` :)

Comment: So is there any way to disable the reference to object?